# Magento 2 - Downloadable product - Stop Versioning of file uploads

Tags: magento, file-upload, magento2, product, file-management

We have opened our store to become a multi-vendor marketplace.

The vendors mostly sell downloadable products

The products are uploaded in zip files so that if the zip is updated then the files can be re-downloaded and the updated contents will be received by the purchaser.

for the admin products we have done this by uploading the zip to our bucket server and using a URL, this way when the replacement is uploaded everything is fine.

The vendors have to use the file upload method.

we are finding that if they upload a zip file "filename.zip" it uploads and everything is fine.

if they re-upload the same file it becomes re-named "filename_1.zip" the first time then "filename_2.zip" ad infinitum for each subsequent re-upload.

Is it possible to stop magento versioning these uploads and instead have it overwrite the original with the new OR if file with the same name detected to delete the file and upload the new and thus retaining the link integrity for people that have purchased it already and also to stop the server filling up with junk files .

managing this manually is going to be near impossible once a few vendors are online and listing multiple products and so need this to be a standard functionality of the file uploads for downloadable products

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance